# Why isn't $\sum_{m=0} ^{k}\frac{k^2 + k -2mk +2m^2} {2}=\frac{(-3k+1)(2k^2+1)}{12}?$

Tags: analysis, summation

The right equation is $$\sum_{m=0} ^{k}\frac{k^2 + k -2mk +2m^2}{2}=\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3}?$$

In my calculation $$\sum_{m=0} ^{k}\frac{k^2 + k -2mk +2m^2}{2}=\frac{(-3k+1)(2k^2+1)}{12}.$$

I don't undestand where the error is. Help: this is my calculation. I hope you understand what I wrote.

[image]

Comment: Without knowing your way of getting the wrong result, we can't know where the error is either.

Comment: @Christoph I added an image of my calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
S
&= \sum_{m=0}^k \frac{k^2+k}{2} - k \sum_{m=0}^k m + \sum_{m=0}^k m^2 \\[6pt]
&= \frac{(k^2+k)(k+1)}{2}-\frac{k\cdot k(k+1)}{2}+\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6} \\[3pt]
&= k(k+1)\left(\frac{k+1}{2} - \frac{k}{2}+\frac{2k+1}{6}\right) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3}
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 3):

You can write your sum as
$$
\frac{k^2+k}{2}\sum_{m=0}^k 1 - k\sum_{m=0}^k m + \sum_{m=0}^k m^2.
$$
Maybe you can take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{m=0} ^{k}\frac{k^2 + k -2mk +2m^2} {2}=\Big(\dfrac{k^2+k}{2}\Big)\sum_{m=0}^{k}1-k\sum_{m=0}^{k}m+\sum_{m=0}^{k}m^2$$
$$\sum_{m=0} ^{k}\frac{k^2 + k -2mk +2m^2} {2}=\dfrac{k^3+k^2}{2}-\dfrac{k^2(k+1)}{2}+\dfrac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is certainly wrong because of the minus sign - the expression becomes negative, which is wrong because of the higher order of $\sum_{m} m^2$ and $\sum_{m} k^2$. How did you calculate the last two expressions? Mind you $\sum_m k^2 = k^2(k+1)$ and $\sum_{m}k= k(k+1)$ because the sum start at 0.

Answer (score 1):

We can use
$$
\sum_{m=0}^k\binom{m}{n}=\binom{k+1}{n+1}
$$
to get
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{m=0}^k\frac{k^2+k-2mk+2m^2}2\\
&=\frac{k^2+k}2\sum_{m=0}^k\overbrace{\binom{m}{0}}^1-k\sum_{m=0}^k\overbrace{\binom{m}{1}}^m+\sum_{m=0}^k\overbrace{\left(2\binom{m}{2}+\binom{m}{1}\right)}^{m^2}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{k^2+k}2\binom{k+1}{1}-k\binom{k+1}{2}+\left(2\binom{k+1}{3}+\binom{k+1}{2}\right)\\[4pt]
&=\frac{k(k+1)^2}2-\frac{k^2(k+1)}2+\left(\frac{(k+1)k(k-1)}3+\frac{k(k+1)}2\right)\\[4pt]
&=\frac{(k+1)k}2+\frac{(k+1)k(k-1)}3+\frac{k(k+1)}2\\[4pt]
&=\frac{(k+1)k(k-1)+3k(k+1)}3\\[4pt]
&=\frac{(k+2)(k+1)k}3
\end{align}
$$